# Scrolling with overflow-y: hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have made this little box that animates from the bottom of the screen on the click of a button, and disappears back down when you click that button again.

It looks and works very nice, but there is a problem. To prevent people from scrolling down and seeing the box, I had `overflow-y: hidden` on the `body`. The thing is, there is a bunch of other content besides that box, and I do want users to be able to scroll down, **while keeping the box hidden and the effect.**

**Main parts of the CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.box-wrapper,
.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  z-index: 9;
}
.box-wrapper {
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  height: 100%;
}
.box-wrapper.hidden {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-wrapper hidden">
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, quos?
  </div>
</div>
```

And then there is a small script that removes `.hidden` on click of the button. You can see a working demo in [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcrv8ywy/1/).

Is there anything I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/pcrv8ywy/2/

```
.box-wrapper,
.box {
position: fixed;
bottom: 2em;
left: 1em;
 z-index: 9;
}

.btn-circle {
background: #069;
color: #fff;
padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
border: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 50%;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
cursor: pointer;
position: fixed;
bottom: 1em;
left: 1em;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but you can't ignore the glitch in the transition. It's not smooth.

Comment: @Gofilord you can solve part of it by removing bottom and left http://jsfiddle.net/pcrv8ywy/3/

Comment: but I do want the box to be in a certain distance from the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
What I needed to do was add an overlay that covers the entire screen, and has the `overflow-y: hidden`. Then, I put everything inside of that. That way, the body is still scrolling but my effect remains.

You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pcrv8ywy/4/).

**EDIT:** This is NOT a good solution, because it covers the entire body and prevents any functionality. I still need help.